# Can you mine XMR on RTX 3060?

Tags: mining, xmrig

I been searching in Internet but I haven't founded anything. 
Can you mine XMR on RTX 3060?
How much hashrate will I get in a pool?

Answer (score 1):

You can mine on GPUs but it will not at all be profitable due to the PoW algorithm RandomX. RandomX is optimized for general purpose CPUs so you will not get any profit from it.

Comment: Which coin should I mine in RTX 3060?

Comment: @david RandomX is not "supposed to be CPU only", it's *optimized* for general-purpose CPUs. Subtle but important difference. And just how *profitable* it is to mine on GPU, has many other factors to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge mining Monero/CPU [Tari](https://www.tari.com/#what-is-tari)/GPU. (currently stage- & testnet)

Comment: What is the value of Tari? 1 Tari = 0 USD?